# SWI-Prolog: Could not open resource database "../../src/swipl.prc"

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I have checked out the SWI-Prolog JPL library, and I am trying to add some functionality. Right now, I am just trying to get the tests to work in the TestJUnit test. However, I am getting the following error:

```
SWI-Prolog: [FATAL ERROR:
Could not open resource database "../../src/swipl.prc": No error]
```

I have looked at the code, and I know that path is coming from this declaration:

```
public static final String startup = 
  (System.getenv("SWIPL_BOOT_FILE") == null ? "../../src/swipl.prc" :
  System.getenv("SWIPL_BOOT_FILE"));
```

It is looking for a an environment variable `%SWIPL_BOOT_FILE%`, so I could see how this might fix the problem. However, I don't know which file I should add as the boot file.

I have tried the `swipl-win.exe`, but that doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Would it not be easier to change the current path used with `../../src/swipl.prc` or move the file `swipl.prc` to the directory it wants. I would avoid the second option in the long run but do it as a quick test of the existing code.

Comment: I want to change as little as possible in the source code, since I hope to make a pull request once I have added the functionality I desire. I can try moving swipl.prc to see if the code works.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the way `../../src/swipl.prc` was written in the code. I was suggesting that you change the location from which you start the app so that it has the correct current directory when it gets to `../../src/swipl.prc`.